# Need MIME file type condition for excel/spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, excel, reactjs, file, mime-types

2nd column values contains file MIME type.

[image]
I need to add a condition, that would be true for all the above file MIME type.
Basically, need a condition for all excel files.

This is what I tried,

```
const isXlsFile = !!(
      file.mimetype &&
      ~file.mimetype.indexOf('spreadsheetml.sheet'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the wanted extensions to an array, get the extension from the [`file.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name) and do the test using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const extensionList = ['xls', 'xlt', 'xla', 'xlsx', 'xltx', 'xlsm', 'xltm', 'xlam', 'xlsb'];

function handleChange(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const extension = file.name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
  
  console.log('extension', extension);

  const isXlsFile = !!extension && extensionList.includes(extension);

  console.log(isXlsFile);
}
```

```html
<input type='file' onChange='handleChange(event)'>
```